# same gmail account has the same user ID in Auth0 even after deletion

Tags: auth0

I am implementing a functionality of removing a user account (the user will have the possibility to delete its account).

I am using Auth0 as authentication provider. If I log in the app using a Gmail account, Auth0 will create the account with user ID value of XXXXX. After I delete the user (through API or from users management section), if I try to access the app again with the same Gmail account then the user ID will still be XXXXX.

This is a problem in my case because I need to anonynimize the data and the other details should never be visible.

I can solve the problem by changing the the ID in my database but for the moment I would like to keep it.

Is this the normal behavior of auth0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good morning tzortzik! I work with the Auth0 Community team and after confirming with one of our senior engineer, some connections the user ID is built based on details originating from the external IDP (Google in this case). That being said, if you remove a user in Auth0 for this instance, the very next time the user logs in/signs up they will receive the same ID that originated from the external IDP. I hope this helps clear some things up. Thanks!